# Why not call the servlet directly? web.xml

Tags: jsp, web.xml

This might be an obvious question to some, but i am trying to get the deeper understanding of JSP web.xml file.

So far my understanding of the web.xml file is that we can map a fictional url to an internal name to a physical servlet.

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>internalName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>dk.something.servlets.Servlet1</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>internalName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/fictionalUrl.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

The end user will see the fictionalUrl.do.

But why dont we just call the servlet directly? Why do we need / want to create an fictional url infront of it?

I tried and Google the subject but all i could get was a vague explanation that calling a servlet directly would be a security risk, but their was no deeper explanation to the subject.

I also see that examples use .do at the end, is their any specific reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

> But why dont we just call the servlet directly? Why do we need / want to create an fictional url infront of it?

That's because the browser doesn't understand JAVA code. Browsers understand a set of languages usually defined with tags (HTML, JSP, XML, ...). If you directly call the servlet into the browser, it won't understand all that code. That's why you need to use a JSP page which contains something that browsers can understand in order to make the bridge between the JAVA code and the browser. This is the [MVC (Model-View-Controller) Framework](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvc_framework/mvc_framework_introduction.htm).

> I also see that examples use .do at the end, is their any specific reason for that?

No, there isn't. You can use .jsp or better, nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
The .jsp page is promoted to a servlet within execution from what i understand, but even if we called the servlet directly the user wouldn't see Java code (even if possible) since we set over request / response objects to a .html or .jsp page (containing html).

So my question still stands of why we dont map the servlet directly in the url instead of going through an internal name.

Comment: Because, you can use many JSPs for one servlet. If you use directly the servlet, you will need to create one for each page you make and that's tedious. Imagine you have 1000 pages in your website, it's not acceptable to create each servlet for each page. But with the mapping, you can map many jsp pages to one servlet. As example, you can use the same servlet for the login, register and logout pages.

Answer (score 1):

> But why dont we just call the servlet directly? Why do we need / want
>   to create an fictional url in front of it?

We need to specify a URL path in order to allow the server to direct the request to the correct servlet. This path can be same/similar to the servlet name, but, for security reasons, we may decide we don't want to expose internals of our application to the outside world. It is, then, good idea to use different a URL path. Another reason to have a different path is that we might want to have a URL path which is *nicer* for end users. Of course, nothing prevents you to have the servlet class, the servlet name and the URL path being almost the same.

*Why don't we map a URL directly to the servlet class and instead we need to go through URL to servlet name to servlet class mapping?* 
Well, we may use same servlet class multiple times, for example if we want to configure servlet class differently for different use cases.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name> 
  <servlet-class>examples.HelloWorld</servlet-class>

  <init-param>
    <param-name>greeting</param-name> 
    <param-value>Welcome</param-value> 
  </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>HelloWorld2</servlet-name> 
  <servlet-class>examples.HelloWorld</servlet-class>

  <init-param>
    <param-name>greeting</param-name> 
    <param-value>Hello</param-value> 
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Note that we may also map multiple URL paths to same servlet, and in early *web.xml* standard one mapping contained only one URL (this is no longer the case since servlet 2.5 standard). There were surely other ways how this could be solved, but early designers for *web.xml* format took the direction to use name to class and then name to URL mapping, as that gave high level of flexibility and configurability.

> I also see that examples use .do at the end, is their any specific
>   reason for that?

It is simply a convention the author chose as he/she found that saying "do" at the end indicates the call to this URL will perform some action.